# How to use map in a function

Tags: dictionary, sml, smlnj, ml

The function in map is pretty easy. I want to double every element in a list which can be done:

```
map(fn x => x * 2);
```

But what if I want to name this function double?

```
fun double = map(fn x => x * 2);
```

Calling this function I get

```
- double [1,2,3];
val it = fn : int list -> int list
```

How can I name this function double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `map (fn x => x * 2)` is a function, which can be bound to an identifier:

```
- val double = map (fn x => x * 2);
val double = fn : int list -> int list

- double [1,2,3];
val it = [2,4,6] : int list
```

The `fun` form is just syntactic sugar. For example:

```
fun name param = ...
```

will be desugared to:

```
val rec name = fn param => ...
```

The `rec` part is a keyword that lets you implement recursive function definitions.

Comment: I thought I was correct with this. The teachers note said name a function double that doubles every element in a list using the high order function map. Just weird wording. Thank you